# Python flanker encoding issue in validating email list

Tags: python

I am using python flanker(https://github.com/mailgun/flanker) for validating email list and I have following code for validating emails list.

validate_email_list.py looks like following

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/third-party-packages')
from flanker.addresslib import address

print address.validate_list(sys.argv[1])
```

Run above code

```
python validate_email_list.py 'sample@gmail.coÃ†m,sample@example.com,test@gmail.com'
```

It's working fine when I remove sample@gmail.coÃ†m

Is this encoding issue ? If yes how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rules for domain names must not be allowing special characters/symbols

Comment: "The rules for domain names must not be allowing special characters/symbols" - Yes. I know, but it should return valid emails(as per validate_list method definition) when I enter valid + invalid emails and this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I fixed this issue by remove email which contains non-ASCII characters from email list validation request and assumed email is invalid if returned response does not contain the email, so the skipped emails are invalid.